# NavigationController StoryboardSegue not showing navigationBar and navigation delegate not called

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uistoryboardsegue

I recently changed my `app structure` to include a `UINavigationController` as base for my `hierarchy` and I had its root `viewController` implement the `UINavigationControllerDelegate` protocol in order to implement `custom segues`.

My `viewController` implements `navigationController:animationControllerForOperation:fromViewController:toViewController:`.

My problem is two-fold:

1. The `navigationController.delegate` methods are not being called.
2. The `navigationBar` is not called in the `views` being pushed via `storyboardSegues` of type `show`.

The `prepareForSegue:sender:` function **is** being called.

This is my UI:

[image: UI]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Turns out that `UIStoryboardSegues` I added **before** I added the `UINavigationController` to my hierarchy are still interpreted as **modal segues**. Probably this is set during *creation*.

The problem was solved by `deleting` and `re-adding` the `segues` in question, with the relevant information (`identifier`, `class`...) transferred to the new instance.

[image: Top bar not shown]

If you have the same problem, when you set `Top Par` to `inferred` in your segued `viewController` you will see no `navigationBar` showing.

After replacing the `segues` the `Top Bar` showed again as normal.

#### Edit:

I posted the question together with this answer, since there was no post on `SO` covering this issue. [self-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Comment: You answer your own question within a minute, this is strange.

Comment: @tonik12 There's actually a `check box` called _Answer your own question_ when you post a question to SO. There was no `post` covering this issue so I created it. [self-answer on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)